# mod_deflate disabled: assets still being gzipped

Tags: apache, codeigniter, apache2

When I execute:

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And refresh & inspect the response headers of my site in Chrome Web Tools, my assets (css and js) are still being marked as `Content-Encoding : gzip`. Y-Slow also confirms that all assets except the actual html document are still compressed.

I have output compression turned off in CodeIgniter's config file:

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

For what it's worth... though with the deflate module disabled I don't think it matters much, my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf` file is the system default:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
</IfModule>
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. What else could be causing my assets to be compressed?

My `.htaccess` file is void of deflate commands.

Comment: why don't you need it to be gzipped?!!

Comment: I obviously need it gzipped in the end. I'm running diagnostics right now. I could just re-enable it and be done with it - but as a developer who desires to know his system from top to bottom...there will always be that big question mark. I hate big question marks. There's a valuable lesson to be learned from whoever can answer this - that to me is more important than anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

to disable the gzip for a specified file try this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI YOUR_FILE_NAME\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

in you `htaccess` file. **`change YOUR_FILE_NAME\.PHP$ to what you need`**.

and to disable the gzip at all try this:

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

in your `htaccess` file.

Comment: To disable http compression for all responses. Can I add SetEnv no-gzip 1 to httpd.conf?